# Rails-Mongoid-Devise: On create, error message "User can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Simply, I'm using Mongoid and Devise in a Rails 5.2 application. In the model files, a User `has_many :trips` and a Trip `belongs_to :user`.  Upon form submission to create a new Trip, the save is failing with the error "User can't be blank".  I can fix the problem by setting `@trip.user = current_user` before the save operation and all looks good in the database and in subsequent queries, but I don't remember having to do this before. It's been a while since I did any real work with Rails (since 1.1, really - yeah, that long), but I don't remember having to do that with an ActiveRecord model.   I was thinking that setting the associations in the model was supposed to take care of that.  Has there been a major change, or is there something different about Mongoid?  I did mess with the params hash (using `trip_params.to_h`) before saving because I need to convert a string to an array, but I don't see any indication of a user in the hash even before I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a trip on the instance of a user object like

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

then

```
@user.create_trip(attributes)
```

then you need not set user while creating a trip.But if you are creating a trip directly like

```
Trip.new(attributes)
trip.save!
```

then you must specify the user while creating trip

No active record takes care if all the associations that are specified for the object are fullfilled or not it doesnt set the associations for us

Comment: Thanks.  I later realized that I must have to do something to identify the user and that model associations are just for setting up the proper foreign key fields in the database.  I also looked over my Rails 1.1 project from years ago and I did, indeed, have to set the user id on creation.  I wasn't familiar with the create_ syntax, though, so I'm happy to have learned something new!

Comment: Thanks happy to help..!!